# Reading csv file with extra line in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to use pandas to manipulate a .txt file but I have extraline as shown in the picture below:
[image]

When i read the file

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('movies.txt',sep='|')
print(df)
```

**I got this as an output:**

```
                                                          +--------+--------------------------+------------+---------------+
NaN                                                id       MovieNAme                  Year         Author                                                         NaN       

+--------+--------------------------+----------... NaN      NaN                        NaN          NaN                                                            NaN       

NaN                                                1234     once upon deadpool                 2017 Alicia                                                         NaN       

+--------+--------------------------+----------... NaN      NaN                        NaN          NaN                                                            NaN       

NaN                                                1244     avengers: endgame                  2014 John                                                           NaN       

+--------+--------------------------+----------... NaN      NaN                        NaN          NaN                                                            NaN       

NaN                                                1245     The bird King                      2017 Mark                                                           NaN       

+--------+--------------------------+----------... NaN      NaN                        NaN          NaN                                                            NaN
```

How can i fix this please and remove this line "---------------------+----------"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "name_of_your_file.txt",
    sep=r"\s*\|\s*",
    comment="+",
    usecols=range(1, 5),
    engine="python",
)
print(df)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, but i have also line text(date/title...) before the tab how can i remove this lines please, When i excute your code i got `Empty DataFrame
Columns: []    
Index: [] `

Comment: @Sun To not clutter the comment section, I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Ok thanks @Andrej Kesely 
here is the link of my own post can You check it please! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210024/ignore-remove-some-lines-when-reading-csv-to-dataframe

Answer (score -1):

Usually, when working with csv we create empty spaces but pandas consider it as a line. do  it's always better to add `DataFrameName.dropna(axis=0, inplace=False)` to drop those empty cells or you can just go to csv and do it manually.