# Ignore/ remove some lines when reading csv to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

i have a similar problem to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209482/12496869), I'm gonna keep working with the data of this poste. Supposed that i have a text file which looks like this.
[image]

How can i remove the rows **highlighted in yellow**

I used the code of @Andrej Kesely:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    "movies.txt",
    sep=r"\s*\|\s*",
    comment="+",
    usecols=range(1, 13),
    engine="python",
)
```

I got :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []    
Index: []
```

Comment: Can you add `skiprows=4` to skip first 4 rows?

Comment: I'll write an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the first `n` rows, `skiprows=` parameter:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "movies.txt",
    sep=r"\s*\|\s*",
    comment="+",
    usecols=range(1, 13),
    skiprows=4,            # <-- add skiprows here
    engine="python",
)
```